# WTL on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, wtl

Has anyone used WTL on Windows 10 already? All applications that I create with WTL segfault on Windows 10. They work on Windows 8 and Windows 7.

I even tried the most basic Hello-World application in WTL on Windows 10 and it segfaults when I run it. There are no clear indications of what is wrong. The program just segfaults with generic Windows segfault error.

Looks like WTL isn't Windows 10 compatible yet? Has anyone had this problem yet.

Just asking here as others will probably have the same problem. I tried two different Windows 10 (pre-release beta, and official release). I'm using latest WTL version `WTL 9.0.4140 Final` (2014-05-30).

Comment: maybe mention this on the sourceforge site or the mail list, what compiler are you using? vs2013 community?

Comment: [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) uses WTL as well (or at least several plugins do). Does it crash on Windows 10 as well? (I cannot try this myself, until Apple ships Windows 10 compatible drivers for Boot Camp.)

Comment: I tried VS 2013 and VS 2010, both compile the executables but it segfaults. I haven't tried compiling foobar. I'm not sure I've all the dependencies to compile it properly.

Comment: There is no source code available for foobar2000. However, **running** it should suffice, to verify whether WTL code can run on Windows 10, and whether the issue is with WTL or your code. You should also note, that there are no *segfaults* on Windows. You are probably confusing this with an *access violation*. At any rate, you can attach a debugger, and see exactly where this happens. Have you done this?

Comment: bodacydo, any news about this?!

Comment: WTL does work on windows 10

Answer (score 3):

All of our commercial applications are WTL built in VS2008. They work fine on Windows 10. If you can get a dmp file you should be able to review the crash dmp in windbg and see what is causing the fault.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 Community compiles and runs WTL sample MemDlg, I used WTL91_5270_Beta

Answer (score 0):

our commercial video application is WTL-based(vs2015 express).

work fine, but it act different to MFC-based applications.

when win10 menu popup, video frame-rate drop in MFC(26fps->10fps), WTL(26fps->5fps).

https://github.com/sailfish009/wtl (WTL Version 9.1 (build 5321 final) 2015-11-17)